# Wikidata SPARQL - Countries and their (still existing) neighbours

Tags: sparql, wikidata, wikidata-api

I want to query the neighbours to a country with SPARQL from Wikidata like [this](https://query.wikidata.org/#SELECT%20%3Fcountry%20%3FcountryLabel%20WHERE%20%7B%20%0A%20%0A%20%20%3Fcountry%20wdt%3AP47%20wd%3AQ183%20.%20%0A%20%20FILTER%20NOT%20EXISTS%7B%20%3Fcountry%20wdt%3AP576%20%3Fdate%20%7D%20%23%20don%27t%20count%20dissolved%20country%20-%20at%20least%20filters%20German%20Democratic%20Republic%0A%20%20SERVICE%20wikibase%3Alabel%20%7B%0A%09%09bd%3AserviceParam%20wikibase%3Alanguage%20%22en%22%20.%0A%09%7D%0A%0A%7D):

```
SELECT ?country ?countryLabel WHERE { 
  ?country wdt:P47 wd:Q183 . 
  FILTER NOT EXISTS{ ?country wdt:P576 ?date } # don't count dissolved country - at least filters German Democratic Republic
  SERVICE wikibase:label {
        bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "en" .
    }
}
```

My issue is that e.g. in this example for neighbours of germany there are still countries shown which does not exist anymore like:

- Kingdom of Denmark or
- Saarland.

**Already tried**

I could already reduce the number by the `FILTER` statement.

**Question**

- How to make the statement to reduce it to 9 countries?
- (also dividing in land boarder and sea boarder would be great)

**Alternative**

- Filtering  at this API would be also fine for me https://www.wikidata.org/w/api.php?action=wbgetentities&ids=Q35
- a database or lists or prepared HashMaps whatever with all countries of the world with neighbours

Comment: @stanislav-kralin thanks for your answer but I don't understandt why you deleted your post? Could you restore it? Your reply SPARQL was really helpful and I just wanted to reply with a further question. 

My question was how to filter the result on only real country borders. Because now I have also EuropeanUnion borders in my result set. Also a hint in how to find this propertiy would be helpful as I was also interested how you came to know that there is a property land and maritime boarder for border (wd:Q133346). I don't see these here: https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Q133346

Comment: Yes, there are problems with European Union borders with this approach.

Comment: It seems that `wd:Q12413618` gives better results. As to maritime and land borders, visit e. g. https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Q3088686. They are rather additional types, not properties. In general, there is no "right" way. All of them are (partial) workarounds for data quality problems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could check entities of type <s>`wd:Q133346` ('border') or</s> `wd:Q12413618` ('international border'):

```
SELECT ?border ?borderLabel ?country1Label ?country2Label ?isLandBorder ?isMaritimeBorder ?constraint {
  VALUES (?country1) {(wd:Q183)}
  ?border wdt:P31 wd:Q12413618 ;
          wdt:P17 ?country1 , ?country2 .
  FILTER (?country1 != ?country2)
  BIND (EXISTS {?border wdt:P31 wd:Q15104814} AS ?isLandBorder)
  BIND (EXISTS {?border wdt:P31 wd:Q3089219} AS ?isMaritimeBorder)
  BIND ((?isLandBorder || ?isMaritimeBorder) AS ?constraint)
  SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "en". }
  } ORDER BY ?country1Label
```

[Try it!](https://query.wikidata.org/#SELECT%20%3Fborder%20%3FborderLabel%20%3Fcountry1Label%20%3Fcountry2Label%20%3FisLandBorder%20%3FisMaritimeBorder%20%3Fconstraint%20%7B%0A%20%20VALUES%20%28%3Fcountry1%29%20%7B%28wd%3AQ183%29%7D%0A%20%20%3Fborder%20wdt%3AP31%20wd%3AQ12413618%20%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20wdt%3AP17%20%3Fcountry1%20%2C%20%3Fcountry2%20.%0A%20%20FILTER%20%28%3Fcountry1%20%21%3D%20%3Fcountry2%29%0A%20%20BIND%20%28EXISTS%20%7B%3Fborder%20wdt%3AP31%20wd%3AQ15104814%7D%20AS%20%3FisLandBorder%29%0A%20%20BIND%20%28EXISTS%20%7B%3Fborder%20wdt%3AP31%20wd%3AQ3089219%7D%20AS%20%3FisMaritimeBorder%29%0A%20%20BIND%20%28%28%3FisLandBorder%20%7C%7C%20%3FisMaritimeBorder%29%20AS%20%3Fconstraint%29%0A%20%20SERVICE%20wikibase%3Alabel%20%7B%20bd%3AserviceParam%20wikibase%3Alanguage%20%22en%22.%20%7D%0A%20%20%7D%20ORDER%20BY%20%3Fcountry1Label%0A)

In some sense, records are duplicated: for the Afghanistan–Uzbekistan border, the list contains both `(?country1=Afganistan,?country2=Uzbekistan)` and `(?country1=Uzbekistan,?country2=Afganistan)`.

---

> - a database or lists or prepared HashMaps whatever with all countries of the world with neighbours

You could ask on https://opendata.stackexchange.com.

Comment: Thanks, just for completeness to filter for one country for others if they come across - 
add  `?country1   wdt:P17 wd:Q159` to filter for a specific country. (Well easy but only thing I could contribute here ;-)  )

Comment: @timguy, you could use [`VALUES`](https://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-query/#inline-data) instead: see update.